# How to get rid of panel indicator in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, indicator, panel

[image]

The indicated icon, when right-clicked, presents a menu that is completely redundant to the right-click menu of the battery icon right beside it.  In addition, hovering over the battery icon gives a power status, while hovering over the indicated icon does nothing.

How can I remove this unwanted icon from my Lubuntu 14.04 panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this icon is related to the Logitech USB wireless mouse.  If you unplug the dongle, the icon goes away.  When the mouse battery gets low, the icon turns red.

That is an OK feature, but it would be nice if it was optional.  However, at this time, there is apparently no way to remove this icon, other than by using a wired mouse.